# Quadrature of a random function

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods

I would like to numerically compute the following integral
$$
\int_a^b f(x) p(x) \mathrm{d} x
$$
for some known smooth function $f(x)$ and unknown smooth function $p(x)$.

I can estimate $p(x)$ by drawing samples from Bernoulli random variable $Y(x)$ with distribution $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(p(x))$.

As a result the estimates of the integral have errors of two types: discretization errors in the $x$ variable and random errors because of the $p(x)$ estimation. My current strategy is to try to adapt Simpson's rule to this problem, but it seems generic enough to have an actually good solution.

The question is twofold:

1. Does this type of problem have a name?
2. Is there a well known solution (preferably already implemented)?